# How to initialize an Uppy instance with an existing instance in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, initialization, uppy

Currently I have a method that initializes Uppy to upload files, that works correctly, the problem I have is that since I have this component on a modal, when I open it again, a new instance is created, and if I had already opened it before and I uploaded an image, the previously uploaded files no longer appear.

I have to mention that I have the value returned by this method stored in a global variable that I can access as `this.uppyInstance` and that is stored when I open it and close the modal.

```
initializeUppy() {
            const uppy = new Uppy({
              restrictions: {
                maxNumberOfFiles: this.isUniq ? 1 : this.numberOfFiles,
                minNumberOfFiles: this.isUniq ? 1 : null,
                allowedFileTypes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png']
              }
            })
            .use(Dashboard, {
                id: 'Dashboard',
                target: '#uppy-container',
                inline: true,
                locale: this.$i18n.locale === 'es' ? Spanish : English,
                note: this.note,
                autoOpenFileEditor: true,
                height: 525
              })
              .use(Webcam, { target: Dashboard })
              .use(DropTarget, { target: '#uppy-container' })
              .use(ImageEditor, {
                target: Dashboard,
                quality: 0.8,
                cropperOptions: {
                  viewMode: 1,
                  background: false,
                  autoCropArea: 1,
                  responsive: true,
                  croppedCanvasOptions: {},
                  cropBoxResizable: false,
                  initialAspectRatio: this.aspectRatio,
                  dragMode: 'move'
                },
                actions: {
                  cropSquare: false,
                  cropWidescreen: false,
                  cropWidescreenVertical: false
                },
                locale: this.$i18n.locale === 'es' ? Spanish : English
              });
      
            uppy.on('complete', result => {
              this.saveImages(result);
            });
      
            uppy.on('file-removed', (file, reason) => {
              this.removeFile(file);
            });
      
            this.uppyMounted = true;
    
            return uppy;
          }
```

What I need to do is that when I reopen the modal, the previous instance will be rendered again in the `#uppy-container` div, but I can't do it since the div remains blank, I have tried this way:

`const uppy = new Uppy(this.uppyInstance)` but it doesn't work, how can I do?

Comment: Uppy has official [vue components](https://uppy.io/docs/vue/), which initialize and remove Uppy UI in Vue. If you don't want to use them, you can still check [the sources](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/blob/main/packages/%40uppy/vue/src/dashboard.js) how to properly add and remove UI for an existing instance (you have to call `.use()` again)